# Child primary key not updated by hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm using hibernate and spring data to save entities in my database. I'm attaching child elements to the parent and vice versa. Everything is saved correctly in the database, as well the child instances.

After calling save method again, the child elements get saved twice. I found out, that the reason is, that the framework does not update the childrens Id after persisting. It is always zero. Parent ID got updated correctly.

Any idea how to solve that?

**Receipt.java:**

```
@Entity    
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "receipts")
public class Receipt {

    private int id;
    /*
    *  [...]
    */

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "receipt_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<ReceiptItem> getReceiptItemList() {
        return receiptItemList;
    }

    private void setReceiptItemList(List<ReceiptItem> receiptItemList) {
        this.receiptItemList = receiptItemList;
    }

    /*
    *  [...]
    */
}
```

**ReceiptItem.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "receipt_items")
public class ReceiptItem {

    private int id;
    /*
    *  [...]
    */

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "receipt_id")

    public Receipt getReceipt() {
        return receipt;
    }

    public void setReceipt(Receipt receipt) {
        this.receipt = receipt;
    }
}
```

**Saving:**

```
item = new ReceiptItem();
item.setReceipt(receipt);

receipt.getReceiptItemList().add(item);

// this should create the new ReceiptItem instance
receiptService.save(receipt);
System.out.println("ItemId: "+item.getId()); //but the id is still 0

// calling save method twice results in a second entry in the database
// instead of updating the previously inserted one
receiptService.save(receipt);
System.out.println("ItemId: "+item.getId());
```

**Output:**

```
ItemId: 0 
ItemId: 0
```

Comment: My crystal ball says the problem is at line 42. If you trust developers more than crystal balls, then post the code.

Comment: sorry, youre right! my fault... I updated my post and embedded some code examples

Comment: How does `Receipt` get it's id? There's no mention of it in the code. If the database tables have auto-generated Ids, then hibernate won't know anything about them unless you explicitly define them in your entities.

Comment: I've updated the code. I wanted it to be lucid, thats why I left out some parts as you can see in the comment lines.

Comment: Start by checking the documentation on how to map a bidirectional OneToMany association. Note the absence of JoinColumn on the many side, and the mandatory presence of a `mappedBy` attribute.

Comment: @JBNizet : that is what I already did before. I took the sample code from https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional (Example 7.22) and got an exception: ERROR: NULL-value in column „receipt_id“ violates not-null-constraint. After removing "insertable" and "updateable" attribute, the error was gone, but problem still exists... any other idea?

Comment: The correct example is 7.21. The one with the mappedBy attribute. We don't know what your save() method does.

Comment: Save method is implemented as mentioned here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts, example 7.21 does not work as well... ItemId: 0
ItemId: 0

Comment: The doc states the save crud operation will either persist or merge the instance.  If merge is used, then the item instance is merged into the managed copy used by JPA.  The managed copy is what will have the ID set, not your detached instance, so you need to check the value in what is passed back.  Try get the item from the list in the returned receipt.

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly what's not working for me... even the instances in the list of the previously saved receipt have 0 als primary key (=id). I've checked that in the debugger...

Comment: Is the `receiptService` on another machine by any chance? Or perhaps in a different runtime on the same machine? It is almost like the Entities you're passing to it are immutable. Can you debug *inside* the `receiptService` to see what's happening immediately after Hibernate's Entity Manager has saved the Entity?

Comment: No, the receiptService is exactly on the same machine. It's just a layer that uses the data repository (see spring data doc). The strange thing is, that the parents Id gets refreshed correctly, but not the child ones. I'll post the debugging steps inside the data repository.

Comment: unfortunately it's not that easy to debug :-/